# Python Azure SDK virtual_machines.run_command

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

Having trouble with the python azure sdk. When running a powershell command from portal.azure.com on the virtual machine "run command" section I am successfully able to execute `New-Item C:\test2.txt`

When I run it from the python azure sdk I am unable to perform this task. It completes and I can see a command was sent to the machine by looking in the activity log for the vm. Am I missing something?

```
def run_command(vm_name):
    compute_client = get_compute_connection()
    
    run_command_parameters = {
      'command_id': 'RunPowerShellScript',
      'script': [
          'New-Item C:\test2.txt'
      ]
    }
    
    command = compute_client.virtual_machines.run_command(
        resource_group,
        vm_name,
        run_command_parameters
    )
    
    r = command.result()
    print(r)

run_command('vm12345')
```

this returns

```
{'additional_properties': {}, 'value': [<azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_12_01.models._models_py3.InstanceViewStatus object at 0x0000029C15A7A108>, <azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_12_01.models._models_py3.InstanceViewStatus object at 0x0000029C15A7A648>]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected type as output `RunCommandResult` you can find the detail here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01.models.runcommandresult?view=azure-python

For instance, to get stdout/stderr: `r.value[0].message`

This other post might help as well: [Run command in linux vm in azure using python sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51478227/run-command-in-linux-vm-in-azure-using-python-sdk/51485744#51485744)

(I work at MS in the SDK team)

Comment: I have looked several times at the example in the second link. I added a print statement to get 'r.value[0].message'. When I run now I get nothing back for the message. I changed 'script' to 'scripts' and get the following return 'This is a sample script with parameters'

Comment: Hi Alex, if you still have trouble at this point please open an issue on the Github tracker: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue caused by the forward slash `'New-Item C:\test2.txt'`. Changing to `'New-Item C:/test2.txt'` resolved the issue.

```
run_command_parameters = {
    'command_id': 'RunPowerShellScript', 
    'script': [
        'New-Item C:/test2.txt'
    ]
}
```